# Displaying direction of movement with points2paths in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, direction

I have a data set containing ship movements. I used the Points2paths plugin in QGIS to connect the points with the ship's names as factor and the time the signal was picked up as sorting value. Now I would like to display the direction of movement in the form of little arrows on the lines.

Not sure if the plugin has this function or if there is any other plugin I might use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the style of your output line layer (*Layer Properties* > *Style*) and change the **Symbol layer type** from "Simple line" to "Marker line" to automatically add more symbol layers:

[image: Style properties]

You can choose the shapes you want the line to consist of (in this case, arrows) along with other options such as intervals, widths and angles of the symbol.