# Displaying direction arrow on pointstopath in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, markers, direction

I found [Displaying direction of movement with points2paths in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119193) which should work but it doesn't.  It looks as though it's an older version of QGIS (I'm using Madeira).  Arrow gives a very strange output with big circles appearing (the track crosses itself and returns to the same point frequently).

I would like a simple arrow between each line point, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If your line layer is showing curved arrows like **(A)** but what you want to see is **(B)**,

[image]

Then, please uncheck the **Curved arrows** option.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Once you know where to look it's obvious!